# Increase Combobox text size

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this basic example of JavaFX combobox:

```
public class JavaFXComboBox extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "Item 1",
                "Item 2",
                "Item 3",
                "Item 4");
        comboBox.setValue("Item 1");

        final Label label = new Label();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Read comboBox");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                label.setText("selectd: " + comboBox.getValue());
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox.setSpacing(5);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label, comboBox, btn);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how I can increase the size of the text insight the combox but keeping the original combobox label size?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Make a combo.css file like-

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-font-size : 15pt;
}

/*added this in an edit*/
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
    -fx-padding: -1 -1 -1 -1;
}
```

and add the line `scene.getStylesheets().add("javafxcombobox/combo.css");`  after the scene is created.

[image]

Some snips from caspian.css will give you things to try.  Play with the padding and see what happens.

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view {
-fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
-fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 8, 0.0 , 0 , 0 );
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
-fx-padding: 4 0 4 5;
-fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to add sub styles in `comboBox.setStyle()` if anyone knows.

Comment: Yes this increases the size of the list but this also increases the width of the combo box. How I can prevent this?

Comment: @brian setStyle(...) only applies the style to the node on which you call it. You can get a reference to nodes below a given node in the scene graph by calling lookup(...) on the node, and then call setStyle(...) on that: `comboBox.lookup(".combo-box-popup .list-view").setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15pt;");`. Using an external css file is much better though.

Comment: @James_D I get a NPE using that code but the documentation seems to suggest it's ok.  Maybe it's only for declared styles using #selector

Comment: Sorry: try `comboBox.lookup(".list-view").setStyle(...);` Not sure exactly why the other doesn't work. You may need to do this after the scene has been rendered (one reason it's better to use an external css file).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set `setCellFactory` on your `comboBox` as shown below after its initialization as shown below -

```
   comboBox.setValue("Item 1");

        comboBox.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                        final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(String item,
                                    boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (item != null) {
                                    setText(item);
                                    setFont(this.getFont().font(this.getFont().getName(), 30.0)); //set your desired size
                                } else {
                                    setText(null);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        return cell;
                    }

                });

        final Label label = new Label();
```

This will helps you.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi peter use this code your drop down size increase but one problem choice box node size not increase.I will work that part if plz check this code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author reegan
 */
public class JavaFXComboBoxStack extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "Item 1",
                "Item 2",
                "Item 3",
                "Item 4");
        comboBox.setValue( "Item 1");

       comboBox.setMaxWidth(10);


       comboBox.setMaxSize(25, 25);

        comboBox.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                    {
                        super.setPrefWidth(10); // Set Drop Down Width 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item,
                            boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item);

                        } else {
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
        final Label label = new Label();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Read comboBox");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                label.setText("selectd: " + comboBox.getValue());
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        vBox.setSpacing(5);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label, comboBox, btn);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ref this example:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/UsingCellFactorytochangethewidthofaComboBoxandtextcolor.htm